Send notifications to the user through a broadcast reciever when battery level reaches 80% or 25%?
I'm trying for a simple app that alerts the user when the battery reaches certain level. One condition is when it drops to 25% and other when it's at 80 or over while charging so it doesn't get to an overcharging point.
I tried implementing it through a Broadcast receiver in the manifest file. This is my code for the receiver:
package com.example.batterymanager

import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.BATTERY_SERVICE
import android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

class BatteryReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    
    

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        fun show80Notification() {
            val notificationManager = context?.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channelID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle("Battery at 80!")
                .setContentText("Your phone is at 80%! Stop charging it!")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build()
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification)

        }

        fun showLowNotification() {
            val notificationManager = context?.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channelID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle("Battery low!")
                .setContentText("Your phone is at 25%! Charge it now!")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build()
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification)

        }

        when (context?.getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE)) {
            80 -> {
                show80Notification()
            }

            25 -> {
                showLowNotification()
            }
        }

    }


}


What am I doing wrong? Nothing happens when battery reaches that level.

The battery broadcast are restricted to only receive them when your app is running

How else could I get the result I want then?

without your app in the foreground you cant, it got restricted in a recent android version. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts

What about foreground services?
